# Hermitian manifold with harmonic holomorphic volume form

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Let **M** be a compact complex 3-manifold with trivial canonical line bundle and **Ω** be the non-vanishing holomorphic 3-form.

If the real and imaginary part of **Ω** are both harmonic with respect to the Hermitian metric *g*, then is the Hermitian metric *kahler* ?

Answer (score 2):

No.  $\Omega = A + i B$ is closed, so $A$ and $B$ (the real and imaginary parts) are closed.  Moreover, with respect to *any* Hermitian metric $g$, we will have  $*_gA = B$ and $*_g B = -A$, so the real and imaginary parts are also co-closed.  Thus, the real and imaginary parts of $\Omega$ are harmonic with respect to any Hermitian metric $g$, so this condition gives you no information about the metric $g$.